# Package wdpar question

Tags: r

I am trying to download protected area data for the Democratic Republic of the Congo (ISO3 code = COD) using the wdpar R package.

```
library(wdpar)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(sf)

cod_raw_pa_data <- wdpa_fetch("COD")
```

I keep getting the following error message.

```
Error in wdpa_data[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sometimes its easier to go to the web site and download directly. https://www.protectedplanet.net/country/CD